# Whether CI/CD SQL Pipeline is supported for NON Azure SQL Versions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Whether CI/CD SQL Pipeline is supported for NON Azure SQL Versions?

We have CI/CD SQL Pipeline for build and deployment. We have SQL Azure 12.0 version.

We also have SQL 2017 version. For 2017 version, we are doing manual deployment.

I was wondering, whether we can setup CI/CD environment structure for NON Azure SQL environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes [`Indeed`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/sql-devops/). You can use SSDT to implement continuous integration and deployment for SQL database Schema.

Here is a [blog](https://mohitgoyal.co/2018/01/10/continuous-integration-and-deployment-for-sql-database-using-ssdt/) on the same.